# How to get content of element in embeded python codes in web2py view

Tags: javascript, python, web2py

I want to know how I can get content of a certain element by a dynamic id/name in embeded python codes in web2py view page?
Basically I want something like:

{{for task in tasks:}}

...

{{=TEXTAREA(task['remark'], _name='remark'+str(task['id']), _id='remark'+str(task['id']), _rows=2)}}
{{=A('OK', _class='button', _href=URL('update_remark', vars=dict(task_id=task['id'], new_remark=**['remark'+str(task['id'])]**)))}}

What I want the **['remark'+str(task['id'])]** do is to get the content automatically but obviously it won't work, I'm wondering how I can achieve this? Is there any API that can help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite clear what you want to do. What is the workflow you are trying to achieve? What does the update_remark function look like? Why is the `new_remark` query string variable a list rather than just a single string?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What I want to do is just click the link 'OK' and go to the action 'update_remark' with args 'task_id' and 'new_remark' to update the TASK table. User types in something in the TEXTAREA, and click the 'OK' to update the background data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Form to achieve this. Working quite well.